# Distinguish between Ansible error and task error in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a command task in an ansible playbook and if it fails I want to run the rescue section. I want the fail state to be if the command failed (exit status != 0) and the stderr output does not contain a certain string, something like this

```
- block:
    - name: some command
      command: "command {{ my_var }}"
      register: command_status
      failed_when: command_status.rc != 0 and "Some text" not in command_status.stderr 
      changed_when: false
  rescue:
    - name: error occurred. Rolling back
      command: rescue-command
```

The problem above is that if the variable `my_var`is not defined above, the command will fail (with a message like `the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined` and the rescue section will run, which is not desired. Is there any way to avoid Ansible taking into consideration Ansible specific errors vs errors coming from the actual command in the play?

I kind of expected the `rc` return value to only be specific to the command but this does not seem to be the case.

I am running Ansible 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly distinguishing between the source of the error, but more of a hack for your use case:

You can add a check for `command_status.cmd` to the rescue section. If the module failed, the variable `command_status.cmd` will not be defined, so the rescue task won't run:

```
- block:
    - name: some command
      command: "command {{ my_var }}"
      register: command_status
      failed_when: command_status.rc != 0 and "Some text" not in command_status.stderr 
      changed_when: false
  rescue:
    - name: error occurred. Rolling back
      command: rescue-command
      when: command_status.cmd is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try but I have looked around and cannot find any documentation on this. Can you go into more details on how exactly this return value gets set?

Comment: Documentation on what?

Comment: Sorry, pressed the comment button too fast. Documentation on the .cmd return value. Cannot find anywhere

Comment: It contains the command being executed - if the task fails because the variable is not defined, it's empty. Just use `debug` module to display the values and see for yourself.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, although then conditional should have been reversed, meaning to run the rescue section when .cmd was defined as I want it to run when the command failed and not when ansible fails

Answer (score 1):

I would expand @techraf's answer with explicit `fail` in case of unexpected error, otherwise Ansible will continue to execute tasks as if nothing bad happened.

```
- block:
    - name: some command
      command: "command {{ my_var }}"
      register: command_status
      failed_when: command_status.rc != 0 and "Some text" not in command_status.stderr 
      changed_when: false
  rescue:
    - fail:
        msg: Unexpected error occurred "{{ command_status.msg }}"
      when: command_status.failed_when_result is undefined

    - name: Expected error occurred. Rolling back
      command: rescue-command
```

This will fail the host if error was unexpected (because `failed_when_result` is defined, if task with `failed_when` is completed); and if error was expected (command failed because of `failed_when` statement, rescue-command will be applied.

Comment: From my experience if an error occurs, the rescue section will only allow you to run a command before it fails completely so I am uncertain what you mean

Comment: My experience is completely different. If the last task in rescue section of a block is `ok`, tasks after the block in question will be executed.